# ImageView collapses and does not display created thumbnail

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I'm trying to take a thumbnail image of a video the user can view in the app and display it in an ImageView. However, when I try to display the thumbnail, it looks like the whole ImageView disappears and no image appears at all.

I tried using a test photo that wasn't a thumbnail, and it definitely displayed in the ImageView, so I don't think it's a problem with the XML, but it could be. I've googled for hours and don't understand where I'm messing up. My code comes from Stack Overflow already.

```
uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getActivity().getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.test);
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(uri.getPath(), Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);

//Create ImageView to hold the thumbnail
ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.mediaPreview);
imageView.setImageBitmap(thumb);
```

XML

```
    <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/startup_dialog"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="25"
  tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/getting_started"
      android:gravity="start"
      android:layout_gravity="start"/>

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/mediaPreview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      />
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Re-read your question and notice the strange bit of: "I don't think the problem is in the XML"... well... I'm glad you think that, but alas, we don't have a crystal ball to see your XML. Since you took the time to write a question, it would be helpful if you also provided more information about this. There's literally no information in your question related to this problem, and you are saying that your code comes from "stack overflow" which gives me an indication you copy-pasted the code without understanding it. Help us, help you. :)

Comment: No, I didn't copy and paste. I literally just used SO to figure out how to make a thumbnail but it doesn't seem to be working. To clarify, the createVideoThumbnail method is what I took from SO.

Comment: I think it might be that I'm not locally storing the videos I'm trying to get the thumbnail for and createVideoThumbnail only works on local SD cards?

Answer (score 0):

The image would be displaying but it is not showing because you may have a image of greater pixel try changing your image pixel or try to add another image instead.